# Ionic 3 Super Tabs Showing Black Screen

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-tabs

I'm trying to use super tabs for ionic 3 and its just showing a black screen and the tabs are not loading correctly (Seen in the picture). Why do you think this is happening?

[image]

**app.module.ts**

```
import { SuperTabsModule } from 'ionic2-super-tabs';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    SuperTabsModule.forRoot()
 ],
```

**tabs.html**

```
<super-tabs>
  <super-tab [root]="tab1Root" title="Home" icon="home"></super-tab>
  <super-tab [root]="tab2Root" title="About" icon="information-circle"></super-tab>
  <super-tab [root]="tab3Root" title="Contact" icon="contacts"></super-tab>
</super-tabs>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install a early version of super tab the current version sometimes has issues this is what worked for me. Run the command

> npm install ionic2-super-tabs@4.1.0 --save

Then restart app it should clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on iOS (black background). I solved it putting all the html content into a ion-content component.

```
<ion-content>  ...mypage...    </ion-content>
```